# Automate a backup of web site on Web Deploy

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, iis, microsoft-web-deploy

I am using Microsoft Web Deploy 2.0 with IIS7 and Visual Studio 2010 "Publish" feature to publish to my server. Is there a way to automate the creation of a backup copy of the old site, either as a copy of the previous website or a zip file?

My hope is that I could roll back to a previous version of the site if need be.

Answer (score -1):

`Backup Utility UI`

uses `System.IO's Directory` and `DirectoryInfo classes` to `create folders`, `delete folders`, and `recursively copy folders from one location to the next`. Utilizes the `DirectoryInfo class` to figure out how old a given folder was, in order to delete it.

[codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/backup_utility_in_c_.aspx)

Comment: Please provide [more substantive details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72002/141525) rather than just posting a link.